# powershell -replace: surround captured regex group with dollar signs like: $group$

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to replace strings like `` url: `= this.url` ``  with `url: $url$`

I got quite close with this:

```
 (Get-Content '.\file') -Replace "``= this.(\w+)``", "$ `$1$"
```

with output `url: $ url$`.
But when I remove extra space then the output breaks.
How can I escape/modify `` "$`$1$" `` so that it works?

Comment: Powershell 7 has a scriptblock based -replace as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
-Replace "``= this\.(\w+)``", '$$$1$$'
```

Note that

- The `.` must be escaped in the regex pattern
- `'$$$1$$'` is a `$$$1$$` string that contains:

  - `$$` - a literal single `$` char
  - `$1` - the backreference to the first capturing group
  - `$$` - a literal single `$` char.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

```bash
# * Consistent use of '...', obviating the need to `-escape ` and $
# * Verbatim $ chars. in the substitution string escaped as $$
# * Capture-group reference $1 represented as ${1} for visual clarity.
(Get-Content .\file) -replace '`= this\.(\w+)`', '$$${1}$$'
```

---

**Background information and guidance**:

- In the **[substitution operand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)** of PowerShell's [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), **a *verbatim* `$` character must be escaped as `$$`**, given that `$`-prefixed tokens have special meaning, namely to refer to results of the regex matching operation, such as `$1` in your command (a reference to what the 1st, unnamed capture group in the search regex captured).

  - Unlike what the docs partially suggest, such a **substitution string is *not* itself a regex**, and any *other* characters are used verbatim.
  - To *programmatically* escape `$` for verbatim use in a substitution string, it's simplest to use the [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) .NET string *method*, which performs _verbatim (literal) replacements (assuming that *all* `$` instance are to be escaped; e.g. `'$foo$'.Replace('$', '$$')`
  - Note that, situationally, a capture-group reference such as `$1` may need to be **disambiguated as `${1}`**, and you may always *choose* to do that for *visual clarity*, as shown above.
- It is only **the *search* operand *is* a regex, and there all characters that are regex *metacharacters* must be `\`-escaped in order to be used *verbatim***, which can be done:

  - character-individually, in string literals (`amount: \$`)
  - programmatically, for entire strings, using 
    [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) (`[regex]::Escape('amount: $')`)
- To **avoid confusion over up-front string interpolation by PowerShell vs. what the .NET regex engine ends up seeing**, it's best to consistently **use [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)** rather than [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).

  - If embedding PowerShell variable values is needed, use techniques such as:

    - string concatenation (`'^' + [regex]::Escape($foo) + '$'`)
    - or `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) (`'^{0}$' -f [regex]::Escape($foo)`)
    - In your case, using `'...'` helps you avoid the `` ` ``-escaping that `"..."` requires to make *PowerShell* treat `$` and `` ` `` (and `"`) verbatim, as shown above.

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 7 version of -replace with a scriptblock 2nd argument.  Just assigning $_ into $a to look at it.  Note the backquote is a special character inside doublequotes, which I'm avoiding.

```
'url: `= this.url`' -replace '`= this\.(\w+)`', {$a = $_; '$' + $_.groups[1] + '$'}

url: $url$


$a

Groups    : {0, 1}
Success   : True
Name      : 0
Captures  : {0}
Index     : 5
Length    : 12
Value     : `= this.url`
ValueSpan :
```